# Shifting Android app development framework without relaunching the app

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, flutter, frameworks

I have an Android/iOS app built with Apache Cordova. I am having some issues in getting some enhancements done to it.

Is it possible to shift to a different architecture of the app like from Apache Cordova to Flutter, without relauncing the app in the AppStore?

It could be Cordova to Native Android App, or hybrid ones like Flutter, but  I want to know if I can change the app development framework architecture.

I have checked in here, but could not get the exact answer.

I dont think it is possible, but I wanted to check one final time before re-architecting. If the answer is yes, please do provide some pointers so that I can take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you sign it with the same key, yes.  The store doesn't know or care what framework an app is written in.  All it cares is that the signing key is the same, and that the version code increases.